# Как разработать прототип словаря синонимов?

Tags: java

> Словарь синонимов украинского языка
>   Разработать прототип словаря синонимов украинского языка. Реализовать методы для просмотра всего словаря, поиска слов, добавления и редактирования словарных статей. Объем словаря не менее 100 слов.

Comment: Опишите, как вы пытались решить эту задачу. Покажите код ваших попыток. Подробно объясните с чем именно возникла у вас проблема и какая конкретно нужна помощь.

Answer (score 1):

1. Создать в БД 2 таблицы: слова и синонимы (каждая запись во 2 таблице будет иметь ссылку на слово)
2. Написать слой DAO для работы с этими данными
3. Собственно сам UI

ПС Ничего сложного в реализации нету

Comment: "Ничего сложного в реализации нету" - отлично. Я могу начать задавать вопросы, каждый из которых будет делать задачу сложнее и сложнее. Например: синонимы образуют изолированные друг от друга группы слов?

Comment: Не учтена проблема омонимов. Я бы делал четырьмя таблицами `слова`, `значения слов`, `синонимичные группы`, `кросс: группы - значения`

Comment: Igor, Anton, Вы как-то странно дополняете ТЗ. Не надо придумывать то, чего там нет.